# Unable to push gem : Home does not appear to be a valid URL

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have just finish building, trying to push the gem i am getting the following errors: There was a problem saving your gem:

> Home does not appear to be a valid URL.

here is my gemspec:

```
# coding: utf-8
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require 'upkeeper/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = "upkeeper"
  spec.version       = Upkeeper::VERSION
  spec.authors       = ["andela-obogbare"]
  spec.email         = ["alexonozor@gmail.com"]

  spec.summary       = %q{File upload gem}
  spec.description   = %q{This is a file uploader gem that will be tied to you model and upload a file for you}
  spec.homepage      = ""
  spec.license       = "MIT"



  spec.files         = `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0").reject { |f| f.match(%r{^(test|spec|features)/}) }
  spec.bindir        = "exe"
  spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^exe/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
  spec.require_paths = ["lib"]

  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.10"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake", "~> 10.0"
end
```

Comment: What command are you using to push your gem that’s giving that error? Just `gem push`? Are there more details in the error message (like a backtrace)?

Comment: no there is no not and i am using gem push.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about this mistake, but what's the problem to set homepage to github page url? That's what I usually see in gems:

```
s.homepage     = 'https://github.com/mdeering/attribute_normalizer'
```